# Property that cutting mats with grids have that cutting mats without grids don't?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's an adjective that describes cutting mats that also have grids drawn on them, and specifically distinguishes them from cutting mats that don't have grids on them?

I guess if there's no cutting-mat-specific word, the word that means "this device has gradations marked on it" (that could also describe rulers, measuring cylinders) would also work.

> That is a ____ cutting mat

Comment: This thing we call a cutting mat has measurements on it — that’s the nature of it. You would need an adjective to describe one that didn’t: *cheap*, *defective*... Are you thinking of a cutting board — a kitchen item that doesn’t have measurements on it?

Comment: Have you tried looking at cutting mats online? There are various different sorts. "With gridlines" seems usual, although some have other designs and some are blank (at least on one side).

Comment: Interesting that the sentence is almost ambiguous; I had to read it several times to distinguish it from _property that cutting mats with grids has that cutting mats without grids doesn't_, where one interprets _cutting mats with(out) grids_ as gerund clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a little old-fashioned and/or rarefied now, the word **graticulated** certainly carries this sense:

> *graticulate* [verb]  (past participle graticulated)
>
> (transitive) To divide into a grid of horizontal and vertical lines.

[[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/graticulate)]

Answer (score 3):

Cutting mats can be found being advertised as *[gridded](https://www.joann.com/36x59-cutting-mat/2622033.html)* and *[gridless](https://www.missouriquiltco.com/products/cutterpillar-glow-addon-gridless-cutting-mat)*.

Answer (score 2):

This is more general than what you're looking for, but the word **ruled** is close. [Collins defines it as:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/ruled)

> having straight lines drawn on
>
> Example: *a ruled grid of horizontal and vertical lines*

Answer (score 1):

I like DW256's answer. However, it appears that you want a word that doesn't include "grid", so . . .

If you just want to refer to the pattern, you could call it "reticulated" or "[reticulate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reticulate)":

> resembling a net or network
> *especially* : having veins, fibers, or lines crossing

Perhaps the most specific adjective for *"this device has gradations marked on it" (that could also describe rulers, measuring cylinders)* would be "graded" or "[graduated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/graduated)"<sup>1</sup>:

> marked with divisions indicating degrees or units of measurement
> a *graduated* cylinder/tube
> *graduated* measuring cups

That being said, I've never heard either of these terms applied to cutting mats. DW256's suggestion (or something similar) would be much more natural.

---

<sup>1</sup> If it only had lines without gradations, then alphabet's suggestion of "ruled" would work better.

Answer (score 0):

> That is a cutting mat **with a grid**

That is a **gridded** cutting mat

> That is a cutting mat **without a grid**

That is a **plain** cutting mat.

OED

> **gridded**, *adj*.
>
> **Covered with, forming, or containing a grid** (in various senses).
>
> 1926   Blackwood's Mag. Dec. 774/2   A white screen, gridded and lettered, covered the wall.

> **plain**, *adj*.
>
> **4.a. Unembellished, without addition or decoration;**
>
> 1976   Derbyshire Times 3 Sept. (Peak ed.) 10/6 (advt.)    *Paving
> slabs... Remanufactured top quality - plain and coloured paving in a
> range of sizes.*